# PHP MYSQL XML ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I have a PHP file which reads the credentials from

```
 require("phpRequireInfo.php");
```

And, my problem is that it keeps giving me error whenever i were to compile it. My php file looks like this:

```
 <?php 
  header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
  require("phpRequireInfo.php"); 
  // Start XML file, create parent node
   $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
   $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
   $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

 // Opens a connection to a MySQL server

  $connection=mysql_connect ($database, $username, $password);
 if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

 $dbname= 'csuser';

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
 if (!$db_selected) {
 die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
 }

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM Bars ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
 // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['Name'] );
} 
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

**And the error i am getting is: "error on line 4 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"**

The XML File looks like this when running the PHP FILE:
       https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJsoW.jpg

Your help will greatly be appreciated

Comment: A picture of the XML file is not very helpful. Can't you post it here in plain text?

Comment: Why does it has 3 empty lines, at the begining? try `ob_start()` before require, and `ob_end_clean()` before echo

Comment: If i did its going to take a lot of text. But here is the link i posted on tinypic: http://tinypic.com/r/inwbkn/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it has 3 empty lines, at the begining?
try ob_start() before require, and ob_end_clean() before echo, to avoid them

```
ob_start();
require("phpRequireInfo.php");
.
.
. 
ob_end_clean();
echo $dom->saveXML();
```